# Developing inside vs outside of Google SDK

Tags: android, ios, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, sdk

Can anyone explain to me what is meant by:

"...the free use of the Google Maps API for development of a mobile application is permitted if the application is developed **using the Google SDK**...

If the application is developed **outside** of the SDK and is publicly available for free to download from app stores..."

What does it mean to develop outside and inside the SDK? If I am using Google Maps SDK to develop a GPS based app for navigation etc. I assume that constitute as **using the Google SDK**

But I dont know what **outside** the SDK means?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this means that if you want to use google maps you have to used their SDK and not use a web interface i.e a UIWebView (It is possible to use google maps in your app using the web(maps.google.com) and using the various web APIs etc). I imagine this is because they don't want slow, badly running maps included in apps, which is what you could get if people try to use their maps through the web interface.

By using their SDK, the programmer no interaction with the web APIs, as this is handled by their SDK which is optimised for mobile development.

Comment: Thanks geminiCoder. That has cleared it up perfectly for me. I get the concept now.